# Flickr GeoJSON fails to load in Python

Tags: python, json, geojson, geo

I'm trying to read in a group of shapefiles released from Flickr, which are located [here](http://code.flickr.net/2011/01/08/flickr-shapefiles-public-dataset-2-0/). I've attempted importing it with both a geojson-focused library and the regular JSON library, but I get the same error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 16 column 4 (char 765)
```

I assume there's something wrong with the JSON in the file. Here's the command I'm using from [pygeoj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGeoj/0.2.4)

```
pygeoj.load(filepath='/flickr_shapefiles/flickr_shapes_localities.geojson')
```

And here's the first few lines of one of the files

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "Flickr Shapes Public Dataset 2.0 - Localities",
    "description": "To the extent possible under law, Flickr has waived all copyright and related or neighboring rights to the Flickr Shapes Public Dataset, Version 2.0. This work is published from the United States. While you are under no obligation to do so, wherever possible it would be extra-super-duper-awesome if you would attribute Flickr.com when using the dataset. Thanks!",
    "license": "http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 4,
            "properties": {
                "woe_id": 4,
                "place_id": "4PrzNyCd",
                "place_type": "locality",
                "place_type_id": 7,
                "label": "Advocate Harbour, Nova Scotia, Canada",
            },
            "geometry":
                {
                    "type": "MultiPolygon",
                    "created": 1292452804,
                    "alpha": 0.0006103515625,
                    "points": 123,
                    "edges": 28,
                    "is_donuthole": 0,
                    "link": {
                        "href": "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5206/shapefiles/4_20101215_40503d67d7.tar.gz",
                    },
                    "bbox": [-64.857444763184,45.287086486816,-64.686729431152,45.383140563965],
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [[-64.783630,45.337303], [-64.763374,45.334953], [-64.725792,45.352398], [-64.711700,45.359261], [-64.686729,45.383141], [-64.708260,45.354263], [-64.705696,45.339539], [-64.725792,45.352398], [-64.758568,45.328918], [-64.763885,45.307491], [-64.764145,45.303268], [-64.765602,45.295658], [-64.766289,45.287205], [-64.774803,45.287086],
```

Comment: `jsonlint` is not happy with the comma at the end of `"label": "Advocate Harbour, Nova Scotia, Canada",`. I'm afraid I don't know the general fix for this (or why it's there) because removing that comma just pushes the problem down to `"href": "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5206/shapefiles/4_20101215_40503d67d7.tar.gz",`

Answer (score 0):

The comment above was correct. I had to read in the file, remove the final commas and create a new json file in order for geojson to correctly read it.

Here's the code I used for that:

```
with open('flickr_shapefiles/flickr_shapes_regions.geojson', 'r') as file:
    data = ""
    for line in file.readlines():
        data += line.replace(" ", "").replace("\t", "").replace("\n", "")

new_data = data.replace(",}", "}")

this = json.loads(new_data)

with open('/flickr_shapefiles/flickr_shapes_regions_fix.geojson', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(this, outfile)
```